# Use pandas to group data daily and weekly based on epoch time

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like,

```
[
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493611200000,
    "price": 4588
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493352000000,
    "price": 4630
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493179200000,
    "price": 4553
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493092800000,
    "price": 4530
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493006400000,
    "price": 4578
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1490572800000,
    "price": 4457
  }
]
```

and I want to aggregate and show graphs for daily prices and weekly average prices.

The daily stats is easy but I am not able to figure out the weekly average. Please note that my epoch is in milliseconds.

I have tried,

```
def get_daily_weekly_and_monthly_aggregates(datewise_prices):
    p_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(datewise_prices)

    daily = p_dataframe.sort_values(by=['arrivalDate'], ascending=[False])[:6]  # for 7 days
    # TODO - This should be configurable. Not hardcoded.
    daily['label'] = daily['arrivalDate'].map(lambda x: pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata').localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000)).strftime("%d %b"))
    daily_list = daily.to_dict('records')

    pandas.to_datetime(p_dataframe['arrivalDate'], unit='ms')
    p_dataframe.set_index(pandas.DatetimeIndex(p_dataframe["arrivalDate"]), inplace=True)
    weekly = p_dataframe.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper("W")).agg(lambda grp: list(grp))
    weekly.mean()
    weekly_list = weekly.to_dict('records')

    return daily_list, weekly_list
```

I get weekly_list as,

```
[
  {
    "arrivalDate": [
      1490054400000,
      1490572800000,
      1493006400000,
      1493092800000,
      1493179200000,
      1493352000000,
      1493611200000
    ],
    "modalPrice": [
      4357,
      4457,
      4578,
      4530,
      4553,
      4630,
      4588
    ]
  }
]
```

which is not desired.

What I actually need is,

```
[
    {
        "week": "1 May to 7 May",
        "avg": 4588
    },
    {
        "week": "24 Apr to 30 Apr",
        "avg": 4572
    },
    {
        "week": "27 Mar to 02 Apr",
        "avg": 4457
    }
]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with aggregating `sum`, last if need remove `NaN` add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
#with borrowing data from piRSquared answer
df['arrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalDate, unit='ms')
df1 = df.resample('W', on='arrivalDate')['price'].sum().dropna().reset_index()
print (df1)
  arrivalDate    price
0  2017-04-02   4457.0
1  2017-04-30  18291.0
2  2017-05-07   4588.0
```

---

Similar solution without parameter `on` in `resample`, instead use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['arrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalDate, unit='ms')
df1 = df.set_index('arrivalDate').resample('W')['price'].sum().dropna().reset_index()
print (df1)
  arrivalDate    price
0  2017-04-02   4457.0
1  2017-04-30  18291.0
2  2017-05-07   4588.0
```

Then convert ranges of datetimes with substracting of `6` days and last create `list`:

```
df1['arrivalDate'] = (df1['arrivalDate']-pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=6)).dt.strftime('%d %b')+
                      ' to ' + 
                      df1['arrivalDate'].dt.strftime('%d %b')

#if prices are always int
df1['price'] = df1['price'].astype(int)
print (df1)
        arrivalDate  price
0  27 Mar to 02 Apr   4457
1  24 Apr to 30 Apr  18291
2  01 May to 07 May   4588

L = df1.to_dict(orient='record')
print (L)
[{'arrivalDate': '27 Mar to 02 Apr', 'price': 4457}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '24 Apr to 30 Apr', 'price': 18291}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '01 May to 07 May', 'price': 4588}]
```

EDIT:

```
#https://bpaste.net/show/909564ed4cb1
data = [
  {
    "price": 3050,
    "arrivalDate": 1489536000000
  },
  {
    "price": 3240,
    "arrivalDate": 1489622400000
  },

...
...

  {
    "price": 3150,
    "arrivalDate": 1493611200000
  },
  {
    "price": 3150,
    "arrivalDate": 1493697600000
  }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['arrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalDate, unit='ms')
df1 = df.resample('W', on='arrivalDate')['price'].sum().dropna().reset_index()
print (df1)
  arrivalDate    price
0  2017-03-19  12460.0
1  2017-03-26  15930.0
2  2017-04-02  15735.0
3  2017-04-09  18880.0
4  2017-04-30  12640.0
5  2017-05-07   6300.0
```

---

```
df1['arrivalDate'] = (df1['arrivalDate'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=6)).dt.strftime('%d %b') + ' to ' + \
                      df1['arrivalDate'].dt.strftime('%d %b')

#if pries are always int
df1['price'] = df1['price'].astype(int)
print (df1)
        arrivalDate  price
0  13 Mar to 19 Mar  12460
1  20 Mar to 26 Mar  15930
2  27 Mar to 02 Apr  15735
3  03 Apr to 09 Apr  18880
4  24 Apr to 30 Apr  12640
5  01 May to 07 May   6300
```

---

```
L = df1.to_dict(orient='record')
print (L)
[{'arrivalDate': '13 Mar to 19 Mar', 'price': 12460}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '20 Mar to 26 Mar', 'price': 15930}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '27 Mar to 02 Apr', 'price': 15735}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '03 Apr to 09 Apr', 'price': 18880}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '24 Apr to 30 Apr', 'price': 12640}, 
 {'arrivalDate': '01 May to 07 May', 'price': 6300}]
```

And for check `df`:

```
print (df)
           arrivalDate  price
0  2017-03-15 00:00:00   3050
1  2017-03-16 00:00:00   3240
2  2017-03-17 00:00:00   3120
3  2017-03-18 00:00:00   3050
4  2017-03-20 00:00:00   3200
5  2017-03-22 00:00:00   3200
6  2017-03-23 00:00:00   3210
7  2017-03-24 00:00:00   3200
8  2017-03-25 00:00:00   3120
9  2017-03-27 00:00:00   3100
10 2017-03-28 00:00:00   3240
11 2017-03-30 00:00:00   3100
12 2017-03-31 00:00:00   3145
13 2017-04-01 00:00:00   3150
14 2017-04-04 00:00:00   3150
15 2017-04-05 00:00:00   3150
16 2017-04-06 00:00:00   3110
17 2017-04-07 00:00:00   3210
18 2017-04-08 00:00:00   3210
19 2017-04-09 00:00:00   3050
20 2017-04-26 04:00:00   3110
21 2017-04-27 04:00:00   3210
22 2017-04-28 04:00:00   3200
23 2017-04-29 04:00:00   3120
24 2017-05-01 04:00:00   3150
25 2017-05-02 04:00:00   3150
```

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with showing week names. With a slightly bigger dataset I am getting weeks as "15 Mar to 21 Mar", "21 Mar to 27 Mar", "18 Apr to 24 Apr", "19 Apr to 25 Apr", "20 Apr to 26 Apr", "22 Apr to 28 Apr", "25 Apr to 01 May", "26 Apr to 02 May", etc.

Comment: It seems first step return bad datetimes, what return `df` after `df['arrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalDate, unit='ms')` for you?

Comment: Your df and mine match. But the end results don't. https://bpaste.net/show/884eea359d0d

Comment: `print (df1)` after resample match also?

Comment: Even after resample, it returns same https://bpaste.net/show/95a98e839803

Comment: Are you sure? because I have different output.

Comment: Is it because our timezones are different? `$ date  Wed May  3 12:29:01 IST 2017`

Comment: It is posssible, I think the best is in first step convert to `UTC`

Comment: But I am thinking if convert from `epoch` how do you get `timezones`? I get no timezones.

Comment: I was missing the assignment `weekly_dataframe = weekly_dataframe.resample('W', on='arrivalDate')['modalPrice'].sum().dropna().reset_index()`. Sorry! Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hey I am suddenly getting `TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood` error these days in a line having `(df1['arrivalDate']-pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=6)).dt.strftime('%d %b')`. My data https://pastebin.com/ysL7HEtn

Comment: I see similar question and unfortunately have no idea what is problem. But it seem it us bug :(

Comment: Allright. On my local machine it works but fails on staging.

Answer (score 4):

See **setup** below for creation of the dataframe `df`

**First**
You want to convert your `'arrivalDate'` column to a `datetime` column with `pd.to_datetime`.  This will allow you to utilize `pandas` built in date funcitonality.  You notice that I use the `unit` parameter where I specify that the value coming in are milliseconds from epoch.

```
df['arrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrivalDate'], unit='ms')
```

Now we can use `pandas` `groupby` with `TimeGrouper` or `resample` in order to perform our aggregation.

***option 1***
*`pd.TimeGrouper`*

```
s = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalDate, unit='ms')).price
s.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).sum().dropna()

arrivalDate
2017-04-02     4457.0
2017-04-30    18291.0
2017-05-07     4588.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

***option 2***
*`pd.Series.resample`*

```
s = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.arrivalDate, unit='ms')).price
s.resample('W').sum().dropna()

arrivalDate
2017-04-02     4457.0
2017-04-30    18291.0
2017-05-07     4588.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

***option 3***
*`pd.Series.resample` with the `on` parameter*
We can skip the updating of the index by using the `on` parameter

```
df['arrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrivalDate'], unit='ms')
df.resample('W', on='arrivalDate').price.sum().dropna()

arrivalDate
2017-04-02     4457.0
2017-04-30    18291.0
2017-05-07     4588.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

---

***timing***

```
%timeit df.resample('W', on='arrivalDate').price.sum().dropna()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop

t 
%timeit df.set_index('arrivalDate').price.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).sum().dropna()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop

%timeit 
%timeit df.set_index('arrivalDate').price.resample('W').sum().dropna()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop
```

## setup

```
data = [
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493611200000,
    "price": 4588
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493352000000,
    "price": 4630
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493179200000,
    "price": 4553
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493092800000,
    "price": 4530
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1493006400000,
    "price": 4578
  },
  {
    "arrivalDate": 1490572800000,
    "price": 4457
  }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: How do I arrange the average according to weeks?